# How to change backgroundColor of a mat-card After subscribe() is good

Tags: angular

A SPA HTML template display either a **List** of books or **Edit** a book, toggled by variable `showEdit`. when a book is clicked from the List:

1. **List** hides and show **Edit**
2. its index in the list will be remembered.
3. when update to DB succeeds via `subscribe()` **Edit** hides and **List** shows.
4. then I can set this mat-card background color to green basd on index from No. 2.

Sounds a good logic and sequence, but `document.getElementById("book" + this.bookindex)` always reports null. I think because `subscribe()` good path doesn't have **List** yet

HTML:

```
<div *ngIf="!showEdit">
  <div *ngFor="let book of Books; let idx=index;" >
    <mat-card id="book{{idx}}">
      <mat-card-content ... (onclick)="rememberIdxShowEdit(book, idx)>...</mat-card-content>
    <mat-car>
  </div>
</div>

<div *ngIf="showEdit">
  ...
  <button (click)="UpdateBook()"
</div>
```

.ts

```
rememberIdxShowEdit(bk: book, idx: number)
{
  this.bookindex = idx;
  this.showEdit = true; 
  // works great here.
  document.getElementById("book" + this.bookindex).style.backgroundColor = "green";  
}
UpdateBook()
{
  this.toUpdateDB.subscribe(
    good => 
    {
      this.showEdit = false;
      // say document.getElementById("book123") is null, maybe List is not fully available yet?
      document.getElementById("book" + this.bookindex).style.backgroundColor = "green";  
    },
    err => {...}
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing to do with `subscribe`.

The key is on `*ngIf`. What it does is to add/remove an element(s) to/from HTML DOM. Not to simply turn on/off the display while the element(s) are still exists in the DOM, that is adjusting the style of `display`.

Solution

> use <div [hidden]="!condition"> instead of <div *ngIf="condition">